Fantasy book about a girl who had a connection with a big cat that was hurt and found a moonstone
I read this book in 2012/2013 about a young girl staying with a relative who ran a vet clinic. She had this connection with a big cat that was hurt. There was mention of a moonstone, I think, and she ended up in the woods a lot. I remember it having the girl on the cover and it was very colourful.  I think she had brown or auburn hair.

This is Circles in the Stream (2001) by Shelly Roberts. It's the first book in the 12-book Avalon: Web of Magic series.
This review notes that the main character is a girl named Emily whose mother works at an animal hospital, and that Emily finds she can communicate with a wild cat that was brought in with strange burns.

Emily Fletcher is the new girl in Stonehill, Pennsylvania. When a wild cat is brought in to her mom's animal hospital with strange burns, Emily finds that this animal can communicate with her. She then discovers that Adriane, who lives on the local wildlife preserve, can also speak with strange animals. These animals seem to think that the girls can help, but how? With the help of a talking ferret (who claims he is a dwarf) and the snobby mayor's daughter, the girls realize that there is a whole other world... and it's in trouble!

This user review notes that there are three main girls in the story -- Emily, Adrian and Kara -- who each find magical gemstones.

Animals are dying at the ravenswood wildlife animal preserve....but these aren’t any ordinary animals, they’re magical animals from another realm. And they’ve been sent to the human world to escape the deadly toxic black fire in their world. Emily’s mom is a veterinarian, and Emily loves animals. Emily is also a mage, one of three, unbeknownst to her and the others. Adrian is the warrior, and Kara is the blazing star. Emily and Adrian have found magical gemstones that contain powerful magic. Kara hasn’t found her gemstone yet, she does in the second book though. The animals that get infected with the black rain have a sickly green glow about them, almost like radiation.

The cover of the book is very colourful and depicts three girls, with a red-headed girl in the centre holding a gemstone.


Yes! Thank you so much :)
